# return results from a function (javascript, nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Could anyone help me with this code? I need to return a value form a routeToRoom function:

```
var sys = require('sys');

function routeToRoom(userId, passw) {
    var roomId = 0;
    var nStore = require('nstore/lib/nstore').extend(require('nstore/lib/nstore/query')());
    var users = nStore.new('data/users.db', function() {

        users.find({
            user: userId,
            pass: passw
        }, (function(err, results) {
            if (err) {
                roomId = -1;
            } else {
                roomId = results.creationix.room;
            }
        }
        ));
    });
    return roomId;
}
sys.puts(routeToRoom("alex", "123"));
```

But I get always: 0

I guess `return roomId;` is executed before `roomId=results.creationix.room`. Could someone help me with this code?

Answer (score 44):

```
function routeToRoom(userId, passw, cb) {
    var roomId = 0;
    var nStore = require('nstore/lib/nstore').extend(require('nstore/lib/nstore/query')());
    var users = nStore.new('data/users.db', function() {
        users.find({
            user: userId,
            pass: passw
        }, function(err, results) {
            if (err) {
                roomId = -1;
            } else {
                roomId = results.creationix.room;
            }
            cb(roomId);
        });
    });
}
routeToRoom("alex", "123", function(id) {
    console.log(id);    
});
```

You need to use callbacks. That's how asynchronous IO works. Btw `sys.puts` is deprecated

Comment: Does exist a format like that?var roomId = takeRoom("alex","123");My problem is I need to save a result into "global" variable to use it in other functions. Thank you!

Comment: @profesoralex your doing it wrong. Rewrite your code. Node is asynchronous. Learn to write asynchronously.

Answer (score 11):

You are trying to execute `an asynchronous function` in a synchronous way, which is unfortunately `not possible in Javascript`.

As you guessed correctly, the `roomId=results`.... is executed when the loading from the DB completes, which is done asynchronously, so AFTER the resto of your code is completed.

Look at this article, it talks about `.insert and not .find`, but the idea is the same : http://metaduck.com/01-asynchronous-iteration-patterns.html

Comment: thank you for your response, Andrzej! The link http://metaduck.com/post/2675027550/asynchronous-iteration-patterns-in-node-js is not working,have you another source? Thanks!

Comment: I just reformatted your question; Simone supplied this answer (you can tell from the name on the right, just above these comments).

Comment: strange, it's working from here .. however, search on google for "nodejs asynchronous patterns", you'll find some articles.